# How to parse socket.io handshake cookie

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, express-session

I am using socket.io along with express sessions.  I am using their middleware to get the cookie in the header, like:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
console.log(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
next();
```

});
which puts this to the console:

```
io=ELJQk5v7q-jjZ5d_AAAA; connect.sid=s%3A17faf004-46c7-4219-9dac-81853ada8cab.ZzFPL%2BpHY9hNxEMDcLesnGEbuZyU9mOwVBZNEBuHzKA
```

Ok, great! Now I have the cookie, but how do I get the information out of it.  I am thoroughly confused.

My session is initialized like this:

```
app.use(session({ //using express-session
genid: function(req) {
    return uuid.v4();
},
secret: 'operation',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true
```

}));

I've searched far and wide over a simple explanation, but I have not found one.  Is it required that I use sessionStore?  If so why?  I've tried different modules that are supposedly set up to handle this, but so far none of them have worked.  I am using MongoDB, so I wouldn't mind storing them there if it is necessary, but I want to avoid using Redis to handle this as others have.

Answer (score 1):

After hours and hours, days and days of searching for a solution to this problem I finally found a solution that will work.  If anyone has similar issues I would encourage them to use the express-socket.io-session module.  It really works great!  It saved me from a lot of frustration. All of the other modules I have tried did not work and were more complicated than I wanted them to be.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Comment: I know this happened over a year ago, but this was just the info I was looking for.  Thanks!